# C# disable datagrid scrolling

Tags: c#, datagrid, scroll

Is is possible to disable `DataGrid` scrolling ? If yes, how ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

In your wpf datagrid set the datagrid property as

```
    <DataGrid Name="mydatagrid" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled 
            "VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
```

Answer (score -3):

You can disable the scrolling using the following properties:

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

However in some cases (such as one I'm stuck with now); when you disable scrolling, using the scroll-wheel over the grid won't work in the more higher FrameworkElements.